# Audacious error pertaining to OSS4 on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, audacious, oss, audio-player

The error reads:

> OSS4 error: The device file is missing from /dev. Perhaps you have not
>   installed and started Open Sound System yet.

The file plays regardless. What should I do?

Comment: Are you running Audacious from a terminal? Or where do you see this message?

Comment: GUI. The error shows up in its own little window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In File, Settings, click on the Audio tab and make sure you have ALSA selected. You shouldn't then see that window:

[image: Audacious settings]